# LXD + SAN + Corosync/Pacemaker: sharing container

Tags: cluster-computing, lxd, pacemaker, san

I have a Pacemaker/Corosync cluster running with a SAN. I try to setup LXD on this environment, but I not able to do.
I can't find a way to put the LXD container environment in a directory on SAN, accessible for all nodes. 
Second way I tried is to use the LXD cluster feature. But I was not able to configure a remote storage on a simple gfs-filesystem directory on SAN. 
Does anyone know a way to put LXD on a shared environment? It would be a similar way as to put it on an nfs filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but which SAN ? I mean it is Brocade SAN or maybe you mean Cisco Iscsi SAN ? 
If it is Brocade SAN. Yes you can but it is very hard decision and you need to use DRBD.
But I think it is not good decision. Better use Block replication VmWare MetroCluster, HUawei HyperMetro or EMC VpLex. 
If you use Cisco Iscsi you need docker share volume. And use NAS disk.

Comment: Brocade Switch, HP SAN. But it is not the problem to share the volumes. The problem is, to bring lxd onto the shared volumes. So that every node can run any container. No need in moving them

Comment: wow it's wrong way if you give present for two servers a volume.

Comment: libvirt/qemu works perfect, fast migration from one node to another. Pacemaker/Corosync garantees single node execution

Comment: I think it is hard way, because it is heartbeat cluster, and if in your network will be loop, then will be big problem. This similar with HP ServiceGuard. But Good Luck.